# Xtext: How to implement IQualifiedNameProvider to return file name

Tags: xtext

I have rule like this in my grammar:

```
`CLASS: 'extends' '=' superClass=[CLASS];`
```

As You can see my class don't have any name like `name=ID` and I would like to reference by a file name that contains CLASS declaration. To achieve this I created custom QualifiedNameProvider that extends `DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider`with:

```
def QualifiedName qualifiedName(CLASSDeclaration cd) {
    var fileName = ???????
    return QualifiedName::create(fileName)
}
```

This works fine when I'm returning hardcoded string but I don't know how to obtain file name where a class is defined.

Thanks for ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `eResource` of an `EObject` to get an URI that you can process to get a file name. Please note: [Class] is short for [Class|ID] which means that a ID is parsed.

If you want to allow a dot for the file name there you may need something like [Class|FQN]

And you may use`IQualifiedNameConverter`
To create the qualified name

Comment: Hi, thanks, this works. I can return file name as my class name in form of calculated value. Sadly this value is lost after a while, and the object is underlined red again. I need to dig more to this.

Comment: It should not be lost. How does your impl look like

Comment: Looks ok for me. Have no idea why that should not work